# JQuery hide() not persisting after hide event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide a visible section then show a hidden section using JQuery `.hide()` and `.show()`. When the event fires (on clicking an image) it only hides the visible section momentarily, then becomes visible again with the previously hidden section now visible below the first visible section. Based on the docs I've read and some tutorials I've watched this shouldn't be happening.

HTML:

```
<div class="transition-div">
<section class="project-section">
  <div class="project-wrapper" id="project-one">
    <div class="desc-text">
      <h2>Header</h2>

    </div>
    <div class="project-image-wrapper">
      <img class="project-image" id="project-img-one" src="images/img1.png">
      <button class="project-button">Button
    </button>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="project-section hidden">
  <div class="project-wrapper">
    <div class="desc-text">
      <h2>Header</h2>

        <p>Some description text</p>

    </div>
    <div class="project-image-wrapper">
      <img class="project-image" src="images/img1.png">
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.hidden').hide();

var slideSection = function() {

$('.project-image-wrapper').click(function() {

  var $parentDiv = $(this).parents('.transition-div');
  var $childToShow = $parentDiv.find('.hidden');
  var $childToHide = $childToShow.siblings('.project-section');

  $childToHide.hide(300, hideActiveSection());

  function hideActiveSection() {
    $childToHide.addClass('hidden');
    $childToShow.show(300, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    });
  }

  });

};

slideSection();
```

How would I get the section I want to hide to do so persistently until I click the currently visible project image to show it? Could my CSS be interfering with what I want to do here? If so I'll post the code. Thanks!

Comment: [Seems to be working to me.](https://jsfiddle.net/0hqhzef4/)

Comment: Maybe your problem is $parentDiv, where you use `parents()` instead of `closest()`

Comment: Your code seems to work as you want to in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u646hpqv/).  I would think there's some other script firing that's making project-image-wrapper visible again.  Or, as you suggested, you could have CSS forcing it to be visible.  To verify whether it's a CSS issue, inspect the DIV using your browser's F12 tools.

Comment: Figured it out. @BenOsborne it was indeed another script that caused the issue. Thanks all.